# Why is the set of naturals closed under addition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was thinking, how are the naturals closed under addition?

How about 1+1-1+1-1...

Or maybe 1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128...

Is an infinite number of operations not allowed? If so, why not?

Comment: You guessed it ... an infinite number of operations is not allowed when they talk about the concept of 'closed under addition'. In fact, addition is here understood as taking exactly two numbers.

Comment: "Addition" is the operation of adding two numbers. Infinite sums are related to addition, but they are not addition.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if a set $S$ is closed under addition, it immediately implies (via an inductive argument) that any finite sum of elements of $S$ is also in $S$. Infinite sums, as your examples show, require a bit more work to define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notion of 'being closed under some operation' is used in the context of abstract algebra's ... and in that context addition is defined as an operation on exactly two numbers. Since adding two natural numbers is always another natural number, we say it is 'closed under addition'

Comment: @LearnerBloke You're welcome!